# Executing long command via ssh in child - does not quit unless I repeatedly press Enter. Unable to locate the source of hang up

Tags: perl, ssh, multiprocessing

I have a perl script which takes a bunch of commands, say command1, command2. The commands supposedly take a long time to complete, about 3-4 hours.

In the script (in perl), for each command, I create (fork) a child process and in that process I execute, `$ ssh s1 "command1"`. Then, I wait for the child to finish.

```
my $exec_command = "ssh $machine \"$command\"";
```

The `$command` is a long computationally intensive cplusplus exec. Nothing too fancy there. In the child,

```
my $out = `$exec_command`;
```

Now, sometimes, it so happens that the child does not quit by itself. I have to repeatedly press Enter and then, the children process quit.

I have googled stuff, but to no avail. I don't even know where the problem is, in ssh or in my child-parent relationship.

Thanks.

Comment: You should show a more complete example. Do you fork or thread? What kind of programs are you running als children?

Comment: Sure. Editing the question to reflect that.

Comment: If the command might be waiting on user input, you could append `</dev/null` to your command string to prevent that (i.e. `my $out=qx($exec_command </dev/null)`)

Comment: @mob: I have implemented what you said. I can only tell if that worked or not may be in a couple of days. The said problem only arises once a day or so. I haven't faced it thus far since I implemented your suggestion. Thanks a ton :).

Comment: @mob: The error persists.

Comment: @zdim: No issues at all. :)